# bootstrap not working with ajax in mvc5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am strucked at twitter bootstrap along with ajax use. Scripts used

[image: Scripts in mvc5]

console errors :

[image]

middle of debug(click event from browser at drop down) bootstrap dropdown coming and again disappearing after debug finish.
before I use ajax request like loading html content on button click bootstrap working fine but after ajax finish bootstrap dropdown not working .
jquery used for ajax is :

```
  $('a[href="/TransJobAddress/NewTransPortJobAddress').on('click', function   createnew(event) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/TransportJobAddress/Create',
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#addAddress').html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert('The server saying:' + errorThrown);

            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Where is wrong in this client side or server side?

[image]

Comment: What is your code actually? Are you bundling bootstrap and its resources? How are you doing the ajax call?

Comment: yes bundled bootstrap please read i have added one more line and i have added jquery used for ajax call

Comment: Thats definitely client side, somehow the bootstrap reference is ignore after you made the first ajax call.
I've seen something similar when adding the JS after the html body, can you reference bootstrap js and css in the head and try.

Comment: I have referenced in head section but still same error.I removed files from bundle and added in layout.cshtml

Comment: I see you are loading the html into the addAddress element, what are you loading there? is it a partial view? or does it contain html, head and body tags?

Comment: I have tried using both partial view and view ,actually scripts are loading from bundle